# Don't understand why this while doesn't stop

Tags: python

I have a selenium bot doing actions on a social network. I would like it to stop after he does a certain number of actions (10 is for the example). I initialize variables this way:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.counter_var = int(0)
    self.max_var = int(10)
```

This is the part performing and counting actions:

```
def action(self, accounts):
    for account in accounts[9:]:
        try:
            self.browser.get(account)
            time.sleep(5)
            like_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                                u'//button[contains(@class, "Heart")]').click()
            self.count_actions()
            print(self.counter_var)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            break

def count_actions(self):
    self.counter_var += 1
```

And this is the loop I've tried to make into main:

```
while self.counter_var < self.max_var:
    searched_category = random.choice(pool_categories)
    accounts = self.load_category(searched_category)
    self.action(accounts)
```

However the bot never stops, even when `counter_var` reaches `10`.

Do you know how to correct it?

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps the exception you are silently catching is preventing your counter from incrementing.

Comment: @khelwood: probably not, since SidGabriel prints the value and reports it reaching 10.

Comment: Do you create any more instances of this class?

Comment: You can go past 10 in the `for` loop in `action()`, because you don't test against the limit until `action()` returns to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's impossible to give a concrete answer to your question, due to the lack of code given, but it looks like the problem is because the `action()` method *doesn't* check `self.counter_var` while the `for` loop within **it** is executing.

Something like the follow might work. Adding `yield` to the `action()` method turns it into a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), which makes it iterable. When that is done it will effectively "pause" at that point each iteration of its `for` loop, and would allow the caller to inspect the current value of `self.counter_var` (or anything else it wanted to do each iteration).

Here's what I'm suggesting with a few explanatory comments:

```
class Class:
    def action(self, accounts):
        for account in accounts[9:]:
            try:
                self.browser.get(account)
                time.sleep(5)
                like_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                                    u'//button[contains(@class, "Heart")]').click()
                self.count_actions()
                print(self.counter_var)
                yield  # Added.
            except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                break

    def count_actions(self):
        self.counter_var += 1

    def main(self):
        while True:
            searched_category = random.choice(pool_categories)
            accounts = self.load_category(searched_category)
            for _ in self.action(accounts):  # Iterate through account checks.
                if self.counter_var < self.max_var:  # Too many actions?
                    break
```